# Developing a Password Sync Plugin for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, password, password-management

Recently i came across through password sync plug-ins provided by many identity management provider vendors (Tivoli, Oracle, CA) they provide a password sync plug-in which we will install on every active directory domain controller. Then we will configure the plug-in with the identity manager servers information. Whenever there is a password is change for any user the password will be sent to the identity manager server to sync with the other target systems like (email,SAP etc).

Reading through this article http://www.enterprise-expert.com/2011/10/how-to-sync-active-directory-passwords.html i came to know there is a module we need to develop and then put it into the registry there by when password is changed it will be propagated to that module which can do anything with that password.

Is there any resource/idea can you give me to implement this module as i wanted to have this kind of functionality of getting notified with the password before it got changed.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for what's known as a [Password Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882(v=vs.85).aspx).  The project [passwdhk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passwdhk/) is a simple example which should help get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for what's known as a [Password Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882(v=vs.85).aspx).  The project [passwdhk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passwdhk/) is a simple example which should help get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Windows Platform SDK for Windows 2003 or 2008 ([SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6510)). Install the Platform SDK and navigate to the samples directory and check the folder PasswordFilter for more samples.